# Comparison between 2 System.Drawing.Brushes fails

Tags: c#, .net, brushes

here's another quirk in .net 4.0 i found:

When i want to check if a variable, which holds a `System.Drawing.Brush`, holds a certain Brush, like:

```
using System.Drawing;

HisCell.Col == Brushes.White
```

it sometimes fails, despite the fact I assigned `Brushes.White` to `HisCell.Col` earlier.

How do i work around this bug?

Comment: Use a debugger. If it's not Brushes.White, what else is it? Maybe it's your fault? A bug in the .NET Framework is not impossible, but a bug in your own code is much more likely.

Comment: Whenever something fails 'sometimes' suspect your code!

Comment: You don't want to work around the bug, you want to *fix* the bug. Chances are, the bug is in *your* code. Find every place that changes `HisCell.Col` and chances are you will find that some other code is modifying its reference.

Comment: Not disposing System.Drawing objects is a standard flaw in a .NET program.  Works for quite a while, every seems to works just fine.  Until the number of repaints out-paces the rate at which the garbage collector runs, kaboom then.  Don't dispose Brushes.White btw, the other ones.

Answer (score 1):

The `Brushes` class creates thread-local copies of its `Brush` objects.  So, if you did a comparison of `Brushes.White` to a value that was *set* on another thread, they'd be different objects and result in false in equality because `Brush` does not implement equality so reference equality would be performed.